# How to write if conditions in .attr using d3 js

Tags: d3.js, polymer-1.0

I have created two if conditions inside the function but it is taking only one if condition and returns that. I need to execute  both if conditions at same time or how can we write condition before .attr('x2', d => self.x(0)) using d3 js

```
function updateLines(select) {
    if(data.filter(d => d.esp != null) || (d => d.esp == 0)){ 
        return select
            .attr('y1', d => self.y(d.esp))
            .attr('y2', d => self.y(d.esp))
            .attr('x1', d => self.x(d.hour)-3)
            .attr('x2', d => self.x(d.hour)+3 + self.x.bandwidth())
    }

    if(data.filter(d => esp == null)){
        return select
            .attr('y1', d => self.y(d.esp))
            .attr('y2', d => self.y(d.esp))
            .attr('x1', d => self.x(0))
            .attr('x2', d => self.x(0))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The checking should happen at the `.attr` level because it will be executed for each element in the selection. You can prepare upfront the data filters and check them in the `.attr` callbacks:

```
function updateLines(select) {
  const nonNull = data.filter(d => d.esp !== null || d.esp === 0);


  select
    .attr('y1', d => self.y(d.esp))
    .attr('y2', d => self.y(d.esp))
    .attr('x1', d => nonNull.contains(d) ? self.x(d.hour)-3 : self.x(0))
    .attr('x2', d => nonNull.contains(d) ? self.x(d.hour)+3 + self.x.bandwidth() : self.x(0))
}
```

assuming that the selection was created with `.data(data)` where `data` is the same array of objects that is used in the `updateLines` function.

Comment: But this is not satisfy both statements.It execute only one either true or false.Lets take my senario data is {null,21,null,45,null,0}.If the value is null hide the chart on particular hour or x-axis if it is 0 display on y-axis.But now it is displayed either null or 0 not satisfying null and 0